# Fabric Beta upload apk with bash script

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is ther a way to upload apk to Fabric Beta using script? I want to upload already signed apk so [this solution](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html) does not meet requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use FastLane for uploading apk to Beta. It has some other useful options and integrations which you can use for continues delivery.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

Comment: fastlane ≠ bash — the question was for a **bash** script. I wish people would stop suggesting alternative tools instead of answering the question.

PS: is fastlane can be used from bash then show an example on how to do that.